# Cannot archive custom class object with NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver

I am trying to perform a simple archive operation to my custom class `Car`. I followed Apple documentation and made it conform to `Codable` protocol:

```
class Car: NSObject, Codable {
    var name: String!

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And i want to archive it like:

```
let car = Car(name: "Ferrari")
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: car)
```

But in the second line the app crashes and i get the following error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtCC11Testing6MainVC3Car encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c4035880' libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

I've searched SO but i only found solutions for structs, whereas i am using a class. What can i do?

Comment: The `NSKeyedArchiver. archivedData(withRootObject:)` method should be used on objects that conform to `NSCoding` _NOT_ `Codable`/`Encodable`/`Decodable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:)` method should be used on objects that conform to `NSCoding` NOT `Codable/Encodable/Decodable`.

If you want your object to implement the `Codable` protocol you can use the `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` like below to achieve the same thing:

```swift
let car = Car(name: "Ferrari")
if let encodedCarData: Data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(car) {
    let decodedCar = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Car.self, from: encodedCarData)
}
```

If you wish to use the `NSKeyedArchiver` instead, you can use the example below:

```swift
class Car: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {

    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return true }

    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String else { return nil }
        self.name = name
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    }

}

let car = Car(name: "Ferrari")
if let encodedCarData = 
    try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: car, 
                                      requiringSecureCoding: false) {
    let decodedCar = 
        try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: Car.self, 
                                               from: encodedCarData)
}
```

You should also note, `archivedData(withRootObject:)` was deprecated in iOS 12.0 and you should use `+archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, is it also possible to use `NSKeyedArchiver` with structs the same way?

Comment: @MuhammedGül unfortunately, `NSKeyedArchiver` can _only_ work on classes that extend `NSObject`. The `Codable` protocol however can handle structs and is the newer more concise and favorable way to achieve the same thing as the `NSKeyedArchiver` approach.